# enabling slow_query without general_log

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

I have been playing a bit to enable slow_query_log, i never got any results until i enabled the general_log (1), but i also get logged ALL the queries, which i do not need, and it causes a performance problem.

Is there a way to get ONLY slow queries logged?

```
show variables like '%log%';
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                             | Value                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| expire_logs_days                          | 3                                                                                                            |
| general_log                               | OFF                                                                                                          |
| general_log_file                          | /var/log/mysql/maria-general.log                                                                             |
| log_error                                 |                                                                                                              |
| log_output                                | FILE                                                                                                         |
| log_queries_not_using_indexes             | OFF                                                                                                          |
| log_slave_updates                         | OFF                                                                                                          |
| log_slow_filter                           | admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk |
| log_slow_rate_limit                       | 5                                                                                                            |
| log_slow_verbosity                        | query_plan,explain                                                                                           |

| log_warnings                              | 1                                                                                                            |
| slow_query_log                            | ON                                                                                                           |
| slow_query_log_file                       | GAweb-slow.log                                                                                               |
| sql_error_log_filename                    | sql_errors.log                                                                                               |
| sql_error_log_rate                        | 1                                                                                                            |
| sql_error_log_rotate                      | OFF                                                                                                          |
| sql_error_log_rotations                   | 9                                                                                                            |
| sql_error_log_size_limit                  | 1000000                                                                                                      |
| sql_log_bin                               | ON                                                                                                           |
| sql_log_off                               | ON                                                                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
80 rows in set (0.01 sec)



show variables like '%slow%';
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                                                                                                        |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| log_slow_filter     | admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk |
| log_slow_rate_limit | 5                                                                                                            |
| log_slow_verbosity  | query_plan,explain                                                                                           |
| slow_launch_time    | 2                                                                                                            |
| slow_query_log      | ON                                                                                                           |
| slow_query_log_file | GAweb-slow.log                                                                                               |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the slowlog to show more, lower `long_query_time` (in my.cnf) to 1 (second) or even less.  Don't turn on the general log.

Hopefully future versions of MySQL will have a default of something less than the virtually useless "10".

Consider using `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog after it has collected some data.

Comment: i finally tracked the issue:
first, i moved mysql data dir (/var/lib/mysql) to another path. and some log variables had /var/log path, while slow log did not. the slow log was being written to my other path! :\